# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - Forloop JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

In my code below, I am able to output the id of the item being returned in the code. But with `console.log({!! $deliver->name !!});` I get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Why is this happening?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  @foreach ($product->items as $deliver)
    //get id
    console.log({!! $deliver->id !!});
    //get name
    console.log({!! $deliver->name !!});
   @endforeach
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Igor He is using the laravel blade template engine to inject variables from php

Comment: In the future please tag your question appropriately as this provides context to what it is your are actually running and why you might be getting an error.

Comment: I don't use Laravel, but maybe you need quotes: `console.log('{!! $deliver->name !!}');`

Comment: Put that in quotes - console.log("{!! $deliver->id !!}");

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for your answer.. That solved it

Answer (score 0):

Since `name` is a string, it needs to be in quotes.

```
console.log('{!! $deliver->name !!}');
```